# Can't get value from class which is retrived from FireBase and display in a setText

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, settext

I have a grid layout with 4 cardviews and I have data in firebase database to be displayed in the cards. The data retrived from Firebase is stored in a class. The thing is I'cant use getter functions and display the data in setText. Whenver I do the app crashes. It is a fragment.

Here is the fragment :

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

usageData fetcheduserdata;
private DatabaseReference uidDatabase;
private DatabaseReference rootDatabase;
View v;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser mUser;
RecyclerView recyclerView;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home,container,false);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.v = view;
    getActivity().setTitle("Home");

    mUser = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    TextView userPoints = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_points);
    TextView userAdrequests = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_adrequests);
    TextView userClicks =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_adclick);
    TextView userRedeemthreshold =  (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_rthreshold);



    final String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    rootDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    uidDatabase = rootDatabase.child("Data").child(uid);
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Integer up = dataSnapshot.child("userPoints").getValue(Integer.class);
            Integer ua = dataSnapshot.child("userAdrequests").getValue(Integer.class);
            Integer uc = dataSnapshot.child("userClicks").getValue(Integer.class);
            Integer ur = dataSnapshot.child("userRedeemthreshold").getValue(Integer.class);
            fetcheduserdata =  new usageData(uid,up,ua,uc,ur);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Fetched UsageData From Firebase", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UsageData Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };

    uidDatabase.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);
    userPoints.setText(String.valueOf(fetcheduserdata.getUserPoints()));
    userAdrequests.setText(fetcheduserdata.getUserAdrequests());
    userClicks.setText(fetcheduserdata.getUserClicks());
    userRedeemthreshold.setText(fetcheduserdata.getUserPoints());
}
}
```

XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".HomeFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Your Performance"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</RelativeLayout>


<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="8"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:padding="14dp"
    android:rowCount="2">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_points"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Points"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_adrequests"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView6"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ad Requests"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">


        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_adclick"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline5"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Ad Clicks"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_columnWeight="2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_rowWeight="2"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="8dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.constraint.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.75" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_rthreshold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="0%"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView7"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Redeem Threshold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</GridLayout>
```

Here is the class UsageData :

```
package com.balaji.earnyourself;

public class usageData {
String userId;
Integer userPoints,userAdrequests,userClicks,userRedeemthreshold;

public usageData(String userId, Integer userPoints, Integer userAdrequests, Integer userClicks, Integer userRedeemthreshold) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userPoints = userPoints;
    this.userAdrequests = userAdrequests;
    this.userClicks = userClicks;
    this.userRedeemthreshold = userRedeemthreshold;
}

public usageData(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
    this.userPoints = 0;
    this.userAdrequests = 0;
    this.userClicks = 0;
    this.userRedeemthreshold = 0;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public int getUserPoints() {
    return userPoints;
}

public void setUserPoints(int userPoints) {
    this.userPoints = userPoints;
}

public int getUserAdrequests() {
    return userAdrequests;
}

public void setUserAdrequests(int userAdrequests) {
    this.userAdrequests = userAdrequests;
}

public int getUserClicks() {
    return userClicks;
}

public void setUserClicks(int userClicks) {
    this.userClicks = userClicks;
}

public int getUserRedeemthreshold() {
    return userRedeemthreshold;
}

public void setUserRedeemthreshold(int userRedeemthreshold) {
    this.userRedeemthreshold = userRedeemthreshold;
}
}
```

How to get through this ? I've tried the ways that I know but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase APIs are `asynchronous`, meaning that `onDataChange()` method returns immediately after it's invoked, and the callback from the `Task` it returns, will be called some time later. There are no guarantees about how long it will take. So it may take from a few hundred milliseconds to a few seconds before that data is available. Because that method returns immediately, the value of your `fetcheduserdata` variable you're trying to use it outside the `onDataChange()` method, will not have been assigned from the callback yet.

Basically, you're trying to use a value synchronously from an API that's asynchronous.  That's not a good idea. You should handle the APIs asynchronously as intended.

A quick solve for this problem would be to move the following lines inside the `onDataChange()` method right after you toast that message:

```
userPoints.setText(String.valueOf(fetcheduserdata.getUserPoints()));
userAdrequests.setText(fetcheduserdata.getUserAdrequests());
userClicks.setText(fetcheduserdata.getUserClicks());
userRedeemthreshold.setText(fetcheduserdata.getUserPoints());
```

Otherwise I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Note that there is no need to create a new object of `usageData` in order to get the data back, you can simply use:

```
userPoints.setText(String.valueOf(up));
```

Comment: No My app is continuously crashing.

Comment: @BaluSk If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: [link] https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hwTYNI-OIcUbjrfCtUmaTn1h_Wm5Mabu

Comment: Move all the code from `onViewCreated` into `onCreateView`. Does it work now?

Comment: No. It is still crashing.

Comment: Your answer is correct. I was manually modifying the database and it caused the crashing.